# React Summernote onInit function causing issue

Tags: reactjs, summernote

I am using react-summernote@2.0.2 and the Issue i am having is that i am not able to set the default value of the editor using `value` or `children` props.

I used `onInit` function approach. The following is the code I am using:

```
<ReactSummernote
  className="ReactSummernote"
  codeview={this.state.codeview}
  options={{
    height: 350,
    dialogsInBody: true,
    toolbar: [
      ["style", ["style"]],
      ["font", ["bold", "underline", "clear"]],
      ["fontname", ["fontname"]],
      ["para", ["ul", "ol", "paragraph"]],
      ["table", ["table"]],
      ["insert", ["link", "picture", "video"]],
      ["view", ["codeview"]]
    ]
  }}
  onChange={(email_body) => {
    console.log("text changed");
    this.setState({email_body});
  }}
  onInit = {() => {
    console.log("Hi INIT")
    $('.ReactSummernote').summernote('code', this.state.email_body);
  }}
/>
```

Here I am using jQuery inside `onInit`. Reason is that I have tried the reference approach and it always got me either an error or the functionality not performed I am targeting for. When I use the above approach (mentioned code), it gives the default value fine. The issue comes when I change the contents of the editor. `onChange` event handler does not work. It does not detect any change in the editor. Now the reason might be that when I use jQuery, it interferes with the React control over the component. But how would I get the functionality out of it.